# Force Safari to include Origin header in jQuery GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, cross-domain

From `https://app.example.com` I'm making the following request:

```
$.get('https://api.example.com', { foo: 'bar' })
  .success(getSuccess)
  .error(getError);
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. Safari does not perform a preflight OPTIONS request or include an `Origin: https://app.example.com` header so the server doesn't return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.example.com` header.

Is there some way to force Safari to include the `Origin` header or to perform the preflight OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0):

You can add headers to the HTTP XHR request in the `beforeSend` event.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.example.com',
  data: { foo: 'bar' },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", "https://app.example.com");
}
})
.success(getSuccess)
.error(getError);
```

Comment: `Origin` is a restricted header and can not be set manually by JavaScript.

Comment: Safari doesn't support this header but restricts adding it manually?

Comment: As far as I know all major browsers restrict adding Origin. Safari supports Origin for POST/DELETE requests (and maybe others). Ideally there is some "enable Origin for GET requests = true" option.